# Disable all Dates in Zebra Date Picker jQuery Plugin prior to a Date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using a jQuery Date Picker plugin called **Zebra DatePicker:**

**Zebra DatePicker:** http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/
**GitHub**: https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/

I am using it on a Project Management app which opens Project Task records in a Modal DIV and sets up this DatePicker to select a Task Due Date.

The plugin has the option to **Disable Dates from being Selected**.  The documentation for setting Date that can be `disabled` and `enabled` is shown below....

What my goal to do is, is to disable all dates that are prior than a `Task creation Date` so that a `Due Date` cannot be set to a date prior to the date the Task record was created!

This code is how you setup the Date picker on an input field and pass in options...

```
$('#datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({
    disabled_dates: 'ARRAY of DISABLED DATES',
    enabled_dates: 'ARRAY of ENABLED DATES',
});
```

---

**Below is the documentation on disabling dates...**

**disabled_dates**

```
mixed   
An array of disabled dates in the following format: ‘day month year weekday’ where “weekday” is optional and can be 0-6 (Saturday to Sunday); The syntax is similar to cron’s syntax: the values are separated by spaces and may contain * (asterisk) – (dash) and , (comma) delimiters:
```

> [‘1 1 2012′] would disable January 1, 2012;
>
> [‘* 1 2012′] would disable all days in January 2012;
>
> [‘1-10 1 2012′] would disable January 1 through 10 in 2012;
>
> [‘1,10 1 2012′] would disable January 1 and 10 in 2012;
>
> [‘1-10,20,22,24 1-3 *’] would disable 1 through 10, plus the 22nd and 24th of January through March for every year;
>
> [‘* * * 0,6′] would disable all Saturdays and Sundays;
>
> [’01 07 2012′, ’02 07 2012′, ‘* 08 2012′] would disable 1st and 2nd of July 2012, and all of August of 2012
>
> Default is FALSE, no disabled dates.
>
> DISABLING ALL DATES AND NOT SPECIFYING AT LEAST ONE ENABLED DATE WILL SEND THE SCRIPT INTO AN INFINITE LOOP SEARCHING FOR AN ENABLED
>   DATE TO DISPLAY!

---

**enabled_dates**

> mixed
>   An array of enabled dates in the same format as required for
>   “disabled_dates” property. To be used together with the
>   “disabled_dates” property by first setting the “disabled_dates”
>   property to something like “[* * * *]” (which will disable everything)
>   and the setting the “enabled_dates” property to, say, “[* * * 0,6]” to
>   enable just weekends.
>        Default is FALSE.

---

**Assuming my Task Creation Date is `2015-04-21`, can someone show me a good way to disable all dates prior to this date?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the `direction`-option?
You can specify a date for that:

```
$('input').Zebra_DatePicker({
    direction: ['2015-04-21', false]
});
```

From the docs:

> 6. Dates can be selected in the future, starting with a specific date

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8eauqavs/)**

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.  It turns out that if a Date has a CSS class named `dp_disabled` on it, that it disables the click events on those dates from being selected!

So using the Callback `onChange()` function, I can apply this CSS class to all dates prior to my specified date!  Works great...

```
onChange: function(view, elements) {

    // on the "days" view...
    if (view == 'days') {

      // iterate through the active elements in the view
      elements.each(function() {


        //if Date is before the Task created date, then add a CSS Class.
        var taskCreatedDate = new Date('2015-04-23');
        var currentDay = new Date($(this).data('date'));

        if (currentDay < taskCreatedDate){

          $(this).addClass('dp_disabled');

        }
      });

    }
},
```